# I don't want to change the position of the listview in android when I reload ListView

Tags: android

I am just fetching the values from the online database and showing in the listview that is working fine but I am trying to update the `ListView` for every second so I am using thread for refresh the `Listview`.

I don't want to change the position of `ListView` to the default position for every reload of the `ListView`it want to remain in the position where I left.

This is my code

```
public class NewSmS extends Activity {

ListView lv;
Handler mHandler;
ProgressDialog pd;
String View="http://localhost/sample/view.php";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_sm_s);
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    this.mHandler = new Handler();
    m_Runnable.run();


    send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SendSms saveSmsLink=new SendSms();
            saveSmsLink.execute(sendSms);
        }
    });


}


private final Runnable m_Runnable = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        ViewUpdate viewupdate=new ViewUpdate();
        viewupdate.execute(View);
        NewSmS.this.mHandler.postDelayed(m_Runnable,1000);            
    }

};


class ViewSms extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>
{
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> param=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

JsonParser parser=new JsonParser();
        return parser.makehttprequest(params[0], "POST", param);

    }

    public void onPostExecute(JSONObject result)
    {
        String numberTwo,smsTime,content,numberOne;
        JSONArray array;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        try {
            array=result.getJSONArray("getrow");
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj=array.getJSONObject(i);
                content=obj.getString("content");
                HashMap<String, String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("content", content);
                list.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String[] from={"content"};
        int[] to={R.id.textView1};
        ListAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(NewSmS.this,list,R.layout.viewContent,from,to);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: activity reload time or listview reload time you want to restore position?

Comment: @Ravi yes I want to restore the position of listivew

Answer (score 0):

```
    String[] from={"content"};
    int[] to={R.id.textView1};
    ListAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(NewSmS.this,list,R.layout.viewContent,from,to);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

put above code in oncreate method of activity.and initialize your list on start of class.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
```

in postexecute method put below line.

```
adapter.notifydatasetchanged() like.
```

Comment: I am getting error like The method notifyDatachange() is undefined for the type ListAdapter  if I use adapter.notifyDatachange()

Comment: adapter.notifydatasetchanged() use this

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
// save index and top position
int index = mList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View v = mList.getChildAt(0);
int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

// notify dataset changed or re-assign adapter here

// restore the position of listview
mList.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to keep your `ListView` scroll position then use below code**

```
  Parcelable state = list.onSaveInstanceState();
  int index = list.getLastVisiblePosition();
  list.setAdapter(adapter);
  list.smoothScrollToPosition(index);
  list.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
```

that can be you can restore position and **how to impliment in your code?** then see below.

```
  public class NewSmS extends Activity {

  ListView lv;
  Handler mHandler;
  ProgressDialog pd;
  String View="http://localhost/sample/view.php";
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_sm_s);
  lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  this.mHandler = new Handler();
  m_Runnable.run();


send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SendSms saveSmsLink=new SendSms();
        saveSmsLink.execute(sendSms);
    }
});


    }


  private final Runnable m_Runnable = new Runnable()
  {
  public void run()
  {
    ViewUpdate viewupdate=new ViewUpdate();
    viewupdate.execute(View);
    NewSmS.this.mHandler.postDelayed(m_Runnable,1000);            
  }

};


  class ViewSms extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>
  {
  @Override
  protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> param=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

  JsonParser parser=new JsonParser();
    return parser.makehttprequest(params[0], "POST", param);

 }

 public void onPostExecute(JSONObject result)
 {
    String numberTwo,smsTime,content,numberOne;
    JSONArray array;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
     try {
        array=result.getJSONArray("getrow");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj=array.getJSONObject(i);
            content=obj.getString("content");
            HashMap<String, String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("content", content);
            list.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String[] from={"content"};
    int[] to={R.id.textView1};
    ListAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(NewSmS.this,list,R.layout.viewContent,from,to);

    // Restore your listview postion here
    Parcelable state = lv.onSaveInstanceState();
    int index = lv.getLastVisiblePosition();
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.smoothScrollToPosition(index);
    lv.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
   }
   }
   }
```

Comment: Am getting error on Parcelable state = list.onSaveInstanceState();The method onSaveInstanceState() is undefined for the type ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>

Comment: @Michael you have to difine object of ListView

Answer (score 0):

> The main issue with above code

is that you are **setting a new adapter every single time which causes the position to be reset to the first one**
This line of code from on post execute

```
String[] from={"content"};
        int[] to={R.id.textView1};
        ListAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(NewSmS.this,list,R.layout.viewContent,from,to);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

is causing it, instead of the above try

```
adapter.notifydatasetchanged()
```

**and modify the same arraylist/array with which you initialized the adapter,**

The list position will automatically stay the same if you try the above